# Flutter.. How to create a backup of sqflite database in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Hello I am currently working on a trailering app in which the trailer can save the requirements of customers and I will save those requirements in SQLite as per the requirement of the project owner of this project that the app will be always offline so if the user/trailer will delete the app or change the mobile and install the app again then they have an option to backup previous data that they saved so how can I create a backup of SQLite plz help me I have only 2 days left to do this project plz help me how can I do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902774/flutter-how-to-backup-and-restore-sqflite-database

Comment: no sir these answer doesn't helped me

Comment: Well, SQLite databases are just files on the device. If you want to backup a file from a device to another, you need to think of a way to transport the file (I suggest cloud). Once the db file is on the new device, you should be able to use it normally.

We need more information to help, such as what you already tried, what specific problem you are stuck on etc. etc.